# CSS Navbar slow on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, lag

So I'm having a strange bug where the code works quickly on my PC browser even when resizing, but the `navbar` is extremely slow when descending on mobile.
Following is the code:

```js
        function response() {
          var x = document.getElementById("nav");
          if (x.className === "navbar") {
              x.className += " responsive";
          } else {
              x.className = "navbar";
          }
        }
```

```css
.navbar {
      font-family:'lemon';
      z-index:9999;
      height:5vw;
      min-height:40px;
      width:100vw;
      background-color:#111010;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .navbar a {
      display:block;
      float:right;
      color:#c2c0c0;
      font-size:1.1vw;
      transition:text-shadow 0.3s;
      padding-right:30px;
      line-height: 5vw;
      height:100%;
    }
    .navbar a:nth-of-type(2) {
      margin-right:60px;
    }
    .navbar a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            height:0px;
            transition: height 0.5s;
      }
      .navbar a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
            font-size: 15px;
      }
      .navbar.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }
      .navbar.responsive a {
        clear:both;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        background-color:#111010;
        height:60px;
      }
      .navbar a:nth-of-type(2) {
        border:none;
        margin-right:0;
      }
      .navbar .button {
        border:none;
        padding:0;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="navbar" id="nav">
      <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-body">
          <img src="Images/Logo - White.svg">
        </div>
        <div class= "banner-tail"></div>
        <div class= "banner-tail"></div>
      </div>

        <a onclick="response()" class="icon" id="menubtn"> <span> &#9776;      </span> </a>

                <a href="#"><span class="button">CONTACT</span></a>
                        <a href="Images/resume - 2.pdf"> <span>RESUME<span> </a>
        <a href="#projects"> <span> PROJECTS</span> </a>
    </div>
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me what could be causing the lag on my phone?

Comment: You can easily achieve this by using bootstrap nav bar

Comment: I'm trying to learn and avoid bootstrap :(

Comment: What phone? What browser?

Comment: I've tried it on multiple phones, and I'm running it on chrome.

Comment: Okay. How slow is it?

Comment: There's a 1 to 2 second delay on it when I click on it on mobile

Comment: https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/KZygLm It is working fine in this pen on an iphone 7 in safari. Does it run fast for you?

Comment: Right so this is working quickly for me as well...but what else could cause my navbar to slow down? There isn't anything else being loaded on my website.

Answer (score 1):

Use fixed position for the nav bar instead of absolute, it will be more faster.

Then use the media queries in css To control the responsiveness of your page, [see the following link for more details](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Finally you have To remove your script and your page when resizing on desktop or accessing from a mobile will be faster.